# Monitors not detected using a Dell DisplayLink dock even after installing the driver for 20.04

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, 20.04, displaylink

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on an HP Elitebook x360 830 G6. I have been wanting to display two monitors through a Dell DisplayLink docking station. I installed the 5.3.1 version of the DisplayLink driver from here https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

This allows me to access usb devices connected through the docking station but it does not display the monitors.

I have tried this with a Windows 10 computer, and it works, so it is not a problem with the docking station but a problem with my machine. I have also tried it with a different Ubuntu computer with success.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have the same problem, no monitor was detected

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable High Resolution mode when connected to a USB-C DP alt mode dock option.
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06575423